# Unable to view visualforce pages in communities?

Tags: visualforce, community

We are planning to migrate from partner portal to salesforce communities. We had some vf pages  embedded in the side bar component and they are perfectly displaying in the partner portal. But when I enabled the communities, created a new one, and assinged the partner profile to the communities I am unable to view the page in the side bar or any other vf pages for that matter in the community. It gets redirected to the 'under construction' page.

These are the permission that have been given:

1) Have enabled the VF and apex classes for the partner profile
2) For every community a profile with guest user license gets created, I have enabled the VF and apex classes there as well.

Also, another thing I observed is the url is a little different in the communities:

```
 customUrlOftheCommunity/path/{recordId}
```

What are the permissions that I may be missing?

**UPDATE** : Earlier I was referring the vf page in the side bar component using the iframe tag and set the src attribute to /apex/vfpage but when I changed it to /communityName/pagename it worked. the page was displayed. But if I have two communities will I have to make the src populated based on the current community? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Have you checked object level permissions on the profile as well?

Comment: I am able view all the tabs and the recrods. Also the VF page in the sidebar component has only a input text box and a button..

Comment: Saw your edit, and have a quick follow-up question... IS there any sensitive data in the page? Could you have it accessible to anyone with the URL?

Comment: No there isn't any sensitive data on the vf page. why?

Comment: You could just open it up to the Force.com Site associated with your community and use that address wherever you want, in a second community or wherever. In other words, because it is in a public site, you can reference it unauthenticated without having to re-create in two communities.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Setup-->Develop-->Sites.  Open the community here. In "Site Visualforce Pages" section, click Edit and Add the VF Pages.